# PHP PDO basic equation vs object and array

Tags: php, pdo

I have finally learned my lesson and switched to PDO.

Now I have quite a few queries but this one I am struggling with. It is supposed to get the individual user_salt during login.

```
function getsalt($email) {
    $sql = "SELECT    *
                FROM users
                WHERE email = '$email'
                LIMIT 1";

    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row);

    print_r( $row['salt']);
};
```

Obviously I only want one record and there will be only one matching record anyway yet this is causing the white screen of death when called.

I must be missing something.

Comment: what lesson did you learn? I have a feeling it was sql injection, and you are about to learn that lesson again...

Comment: So you switched to PDO and "learned your lesson", yet you aren't using a prepared statement that has an input? There is so many things wrong with these 2 lines of code. 1) Use a prepared statement. 2) Does $db have scope in this function. 3)Why are you doing select * when you only want the salt? Do select salt

Comment: Arrrr. Perhaps you could advise me..

Comment: Congratulations on switching to PDO. I've been preaching on this subject for a long time, and it seems people don't learn their lesson until it's too late.

Comment: @ScottyC. Too late for what? Too late for whoom? One botched project will get any developer thinking. One botched project is not the end of a carrier it's most likely the start of most carriers ;-).

Comment: @MihaiStancu Yeah, poor choice of words on my part. I meant that most people don't realize what they're doing is wrong until someone takes advantage of their lazy coding. ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for the `foreach` you used.

Also as others pointed out you should use prepared statements.

You should also be sure to check that the result of a DB query really was successful.

```
function getsalt($email) {
    $sql = "SELECT      salt
                FROM    users
                WHERE   email = ':email'
                LIMIT   1";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    if($stmt === FALSE)
        return(FALSE);

    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $salt = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    print_r( $salt );
}
```

If:

- your query didn't have parameters (a simple select or a create/alter);
- you didn't want to check if DB query was successful;
- you really really want to write a query as a one-liner;

You can:

```
foreach($pdo->query('SHOW TABLES')->fetchAll() AS $row) print_r($row);
```

Comment: "If your query didn't have any parameters *supplied by the user*." would be more appropriate. There's nothing wrong sending "parameters" that you know are safe in a query.

Comment: This is the best answer IMO, but it's still selecting every column when he's only looking to select the salt.

Comment: @ScottyC. there now it just fetches one column worth of data both in the SQL and in PDO.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely getting an error on `query()`. You'll need to check it like below.

This function will return `false` if any errors, or the salt if all goes well:

```
function getSalt($email) {
    $sql = "SELECT salt FROM users WHERE email = '$email'"; 
    $resultSet=$db->query($sql);
    if (!$resultSet) return false;
    return $resultSet->fetchColumn(); 
};
```

To avoid SQL injection attacks, be sure to validate the format of `$email` before passing it to the function.

Comment: I have never used pdo->query, but I wonder why the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php says otherwise right in their  (only) example

Comment: Huh. Learn something new every day. I just tried a similar example using the technique you originally posted. It works. You likely then are getting an error in your `query()` call. Check if it is returning `false`.

Comment: `PDOStatement` is `Traversable`, so yes, you can `foreach` directly on it.

Comment: @Robin, You'll also want to check the format of `$email` to make sure it doesn't have any illegal characters in it (spaces, semicolons, etc) which could be used for a SQL injection attack. Also, using prepared statements helps (but does not ensure) against SQL injection attacks.